# Trouble accessing values from appdelegate with multiple views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to access int's and float's that I created as properties in my AppDelegate from views that are created as subviews of the apps view controller (I know it's a no-no and I should use MVC paradigm but this is for a class and we didn't cover that this semester).  I can set the values from each view and then get them in the same view, but when I want to aggregate all the values into one view I can't access anything.  In the `viewWillDisappear` method of each view I have:

`Final2AppDelegate* delegate = (Final2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

Followed by the values I want to set:
`...
delegate.oldTotal = olds;
...`

Then on the view that aggregates all the values I have labels whose text is supposed to be set to the values stored in `delegate` but all I get are 0's.  I'm not sure if the views are calling the `willAppear` and `willDisappear` methods since they are being controlled as:

```
-(IBAction)loadBeverageView:(id)sender{
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:beverageViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

and

```
-(void)clearView{
    if(beverageViewController.view.superview){
        [beverageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if(appetizerViewController.view.superview){
        [appetizerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if(entreeViewController.view.superview){
        [entreeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if(sideViewController.view.superview){
        [sideViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }else if(dessertViewController.view.superview){
        [dessertViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }else{
        [billViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

I have spent days just trying to get this to work and have nothing to show.  Can anyone shed some light here?

---

### AppDelegate code and code I'm using to access it

---

I have the integers and floats I've been trying to use as so:

`int eggTotal;`
and
`@property(nonatomic,assign)int eggTotal;`

Then they are all `synthesized` in the implementation file.  I've been assigning the values like this:

```
Final2AppDelegate* delegate = (Final2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
delegate.oldTotal = olds;
```

and I've been trying to access them like this:

```
eggFinalQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",delegate.eggTotal];
```

Comment: How are you storing the `ints` and `floats`—do you use `@property` and `@sythesize`?

Comment: Yes, I'm storing them as properties of AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `-(void) clearView` needs to be that complicated. If you simply want to remove the view you have previously set, try this:

```
-(void) clearView {
    if ([[self.view subviews] count] > 0) {
        [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Note I just typed this in, so watch out for typos.

This also becomes much simpler if `self.view` only contains the view you are adding. Rather than using index 0, you can do this:

```
-(IBAction)loadBeverageView:(id)sender{
    [self clearView];
    [self.view addSubview:beverageViewController.view];
}
```

and ....

```
-(void) clearView {
    if ([[self.view subviews] count] > 0) {
        [[[self.view subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that's more complicated than it has to be but that's not the issue, I'm having trouble accessing the data that I've stores in the AppDelegate

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to post code showing how your App delegate is setup and the code that accesses it.